# Взаимодействие с сторонними приложениями

Tags: android, python, kivy

Возможно ли организовать взаимодействие из моего приложения с другими приложениями в Android. Например со Steam приложением (именно мобильным приложением, не веб апи и тд). К примеру, получить код авторизации (чтобы организовать авторизацию без лишних кликов и вводов). Если что, код пишу на Kivy Python. Если нет, то можете подробно расписать, как вообще в Android организованно взаимодействие с другими приложениями.

Comment: Не нужно использовать метки `api` и `steam`. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/api/info

Comment: Я лично был бы очень недоволен таким функционалом. Мне гораздо приятней самому заходить в стороннее приложение и копировать код, нежели осознавать тот факт, что приложение само забирает подобные "секретные" коды. Это же по сути мошенничество. Я понимаю что вы, возможно, белый и пушистый. Но не все такие.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наткнулся на [пример интеграции WhatsApp в своё приложение](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

В Web применяются трюки в виде ссылок:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">hi</a>
```

Посмотрите как работает [декомпилированный клиент](https://github.com/SuitedButler/com.valvesoftware.android.steam.community) для того чтобы выяснить, есть ли у пакета подобные интерфейсы.

Answer (score 3):

Взаимодействие с другими приложениями на телефоне происходит через намерения. Например, инициировать телефонный звонок можно следующим образом:

```
Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:5551234");  //в Uri указывается номер телефона
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
```

Подробнее смотрите [тут](http://www.fandroid.info/otpravka-polzovatelya-v-drugoe-prilozhenie/).

**UPD: Пример НЕ с системными приложениями и функциями**

Подобно тому, как вы создаёте намерения с действием `ACTION_SEND` для отправки данных в другое приложение, вы можете создавать фильтры намерений для того, чтобы иметь возможность получать намерения с этим действием. Для этого вам нужно определить фильтр намерений в манифесте, используя элемент `<intent-filter>`. Например, если ваше приложение обрабатывает прием текстового содержимого, ваш манифест должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

И в случае, когда другое приложение будет передавать с помощью намерения текст, передавая намерение в метод `startActivity()`, в числе приёмщиков этого намерения будет ваше приложение. И если из этого списка пользователь выберет ваше приложение, будет запущена соответствующая активность (`.MainActivity` в приведенном выше примере) вашего приложения. Именно тогда до вас, чтобы управлять содержимым надлежащим образом в пределах вашего кода и пользовательского интерфейса. Как обрабатывать принятый текст в вашем приложение дальше, зависит от вашего желания.

Comment: ну мне бы желательно на примере не с системными приложениями и функциями пример

Comment: @Corle, обновила ответ